# The Alshich's explanation on the machatzis hashekel

Tags: commentaries, translation, parashat-ki-tisa, alshich

The [Alshich HaKodesh (Shemos, 30:13, sv. והנה על דבר שיעור מחצית השקל ולא שקל שלם)](https://www.sefaria.org/Alshikh_on_Torah%2C_Exodus.30.13.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) seems to explain what the reason is behind the machatzis hashekel - the half shekel - he seems to be saying that the half shekel reminds us that we are not "complete".

> והנה על דבר שיעור מחצית השקל ולא שקל שלם. ארז"ל הטעם מפני שהע"ג שקולה כעובר י' הדברות. ע"כ הביאו י' גרה ובשם החכם הר"ש בן אלקביץ ז"ל שמעתי שהוא להורות את בני ישראל יחס אחדותם בל יעלה על לב איש מהם שהוא נפרד מחברו כ"א כאלו כל א' חצי ובהתחברו עם כל א' וא' מישראל נעשה אחד שלם. ע"כ כל א' יביאה מחצית:
> והנה עדין צריך לבקש טעם למה זה למדנו ית' ענין זה פה והנני אבא אחריו ומלאתי את דבריו והוא כי אחרי או' יתברך ונתנו איש כופר נפשו ראה והנה יתחמץ לבב אנוש באמור על מה זה עונש אענש לאשמת העם כי יצוו עלי אתן כופר נפשי על עון אשר עושיו כבר מתו ולא יומת איש על עונו כי גם שלא מחינו הנשארים מי עשאנו ערבים. ע"כ רמז לנו יתברך כי כל איש מישראל נפשו קשורה בחברו כי ממקור א' הן ונפשות כל אישי ישראל לאחת יחשבו. ע"כ יביא כל א' מחצית להורות כי כל א' עם כל איש זולתו אחד הוא ובכן הם ערבים זה לזה

Could someone maybe explain what the Alshich is saying here? I have trouble understanding what he means with "that we are not complete". What is, according to the Alshich, the reason behind the half-shekel?

Comment: He basically says it’s to show we’re not complete, we need help, and either we need hashem’s help, or another Yid’s.

Comment: @hayam but why the half shekel?

Comment: This part I’m about to say is my own Pishat, but, I’d say it’s since in this world money is everything to most people, but Hashem is telling us that that’s just one half, the other half is help from others/hashem, and learning

Comment: The half-shekel symbolizes that we're each only a fraction of the unit that is the Jewish people, and we're only whole when we're united. That's also why it's called a "redemption," to remind us that we share collective responsibility for each other's shortcomings.

Comment: @shmosel interesting. Is this what the Alshich says, or is this your chiddush?

Comment: That's what it says.

Comment: @shmosel would you be able to translate the piece and put it into an answer so I can award it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, he's saying the half-shekel symbolizes that we're each only a fraction of the unit that is the Jewish people, and we're only whole when we're united. That's also why it's called an "atonement," to remind us that we share collective responsibility for each other's failings.

Here's a more direct translation:

> On the matter of the measure of a half-shekel rather than a whole
> shekel, our sages explain that it's because idol worship is equivalent
> to violating the Ten Commandments, therefore they brought ten *gerah*
> [as atonement].
>
> I heard in the name of the sage R' Shlomo Alkabetz z"l that it's a
> lesson to the Jews about unity, that no one should think he's
> independent from his fellow. Rather, it's as though each person is a
> half, and by joining with every other Jew he becomes whole. Therefore,
> each person brought [only] a half-shekel.
>
> However, we still need to explain why this lesson is taught
> [specifically] here. Therefore, I will further expand on his words:
> Hashem said "every man will give an atonement for his soul." This might
> seem troubling, as one may ask, "Why should I share in the punishment
> of the nation, such that I'm commanded to give an atonement for my soul,
> for sins whose transgressors have already died?" ... In response,
> Hashem is hinting that every Jewish soul is bound with his fellow,
> because they all stem from the same Source, thus the souls of all Jews
> are like one entity. That's why each person brought a half-shekel, to
> indicate that each person is one with every other person, and
> therefore they are each responsible for one another.

I left the following fragment untranslated, as I didn't fully understand it:

> ולא יומת איש על עונו כי גם שלא מחינו הנשארים מי עשאנו ערבים

If anyone can help, please reply in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :) Gut Shabbos.